# I have a human friend whose name is Siri, so can I change iPhone's Siri to another name?

Tags: siri

I have a friend who is named Siri (as [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siri_(given_name)), the Scandinavian name had "high popularity in the 20th century"). Unfortunately, conversations often go like this:

> Me: Hey Siri! How are you?
>
> Siri (person): Great, how are —
>
> Siri (digital assistant): Very well, thank you!

I know that I can turn off "Hey Siri" entirely, but I'd kind of like to keep it on if I can. Is there any way to change Siri's name to something else? I know that Amazon Echo has a similar thing where you can change the name from "Alexa" to "Amazon", and I would like to do the same thing for Siri.

Also, I sometimes use the button to activate Siri and out of habit speak commands like "Siri, what's the weather like?", even though I know that "Siri" is optional. I'd like a solution that would work with that as well (although changing "Hey Siri" is a bigger concern).

Comment: Nope. Siri is, for better or for worse, stuck as Siri. You can download the Alexa app to have Alexa as a personal assistant and just shut off "Hey Siri"—or even try Hound.

Comment: One solution would be for your friend to change her name.

Comment: @Phong Somehow I don't think she'll go for that.